# Passing Redux action to nested child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following structure

```
UserPage -> Container
|-----UserList -> Dumb Component
|--- User ->Dumb Component
```

My action and dispatch obviously is connected to container which is UserPage

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    };
}


function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({deleteUser: deleteUser}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserPage);
```

Now I am passing deleteUser action to the UserList Component as 
    and then from UserList to the User as

```
class UserList extends React.Component {
    userList() {
        return this.props.users.map(function(user, i){
            return(
                <User key={i} user={user} deleteUser={this.props.deleteUser} />
                );
        });
    }
}
```

and finally my leaf component User has this code

```
class User extends React.Component {

            render() {
                console.info(this.props.deleteUser);
                var user = this.props.user
                return(
                    <tr>
                    <td>{user.id}</td>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                    <td>{user.createdAt}</td>
                    <td>{user.updatedAt}</td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="#" onClick={()=>this.props.deleteUser(user)}> Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    );
            }
        }

        export default User;
```

Now when I pass delete user from UserList to User I get this error

> app.bundle.js:29210 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

BTW  I tried treating deleteUser as function by passing it as ()=>delete user,  but I  still get that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userList() {
    return this.props.users.map(function(user, i){
        return(
            <User key={i} user={user} deleteUser={this.props.deleteUser} />
        );
    });
}
```

> should be

```
userList() {
    return this.props.users.map((user, i) => {
        return(
            <User key={i} user={user} deleteUser={this.props.deleteUser} />
        );
    });
}
```

because `function(user, i){}` has its own this. but using `(user, i) => {}` previous this is preserved. Learn more on arrow functions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Your answer is more explicit and it worked thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserList#userList` method doesn't have the `this` you expect. Use an arrow function to preserve the `this` at the place the function is defined:

```
userList() {
  return this.props.users.map((user, i) => (
    <User key={i} user={user} deleteUser={this.props.deleteUser} />
  )
}
```

See [`this` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)